# How to generate a CGVector with two CGPoint in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, sprite

I'm developing a small game in `Swift 3`. I want to move my enemies to the character position, I tried to use this function:

```
let actionTransaction6 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 
personaje.position.x, y:personaje.position.y ), duration: 6.0 -  
Double(nivel))

enemigo6.run(actionTransaction6)
```

But the enemies stop when they arrive at the initial point of my character. I know that there's a function to move to an specific direction, but I wasn't be able to "find" my CGVector. 
It might be something like this or what?

```
SKAction.move(by: enemigo6.position - personaje.position, duration: 10)
```

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `-` operator defined for `CGPoint` and there is no function to create a `CGVector` from two points.

Just create the vector manually from components:

```
let movement = CGVector(
    x: enemigo6.x - personaje.position.x,
    y: enemigo6.y - personaje.position.y
)
SKAction.move(by: movement, duration: 10)
```

Comment: The SKAction.move(by: ..., duration: ...) do the same as the the SKAction.move(to: ..., duration: ...) and I don't know why... @Sulthan

Answer (score 3):

Make your own extension

```
import UIKit

extension CGPoint {
    static func - (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGVector {
        return  CGVector(dx: lhs.x - rhs.x, dy: lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }
}
```

Then you will get CGVector = CGPoint - CGPoint. So you will be able to use your code:

```
SKAction.move(by: enemigo6.position - personaje.position, duration: 10)
```

Just in case you will need another operations

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func + (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGVector) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: lhs.x + rhs.dx, y: lhs.y + rhs.dy)
    }

    static func - (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGVector) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: lhs.x - rhs.dx, y: lhs.y - rhs.dy)
    }

    static func - (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGVector {
        return  CGVector(dx: lhs.x - rhs.x, dy: lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }
}
```